# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch Device(#xxxx) expected, got String(#xxxx)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, associations

I'm getting the following error... ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch Device(#xxxx) expected, got String(#xxxx)

I cant see to work out where this error is coming from or how to solve it. Can anyone explain where my code is going wrong?

Models =

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :from_links, class_name: "Link", foreign_key: "from_device"
  has_many :to_links, class_name: "Link", foreign_key: "to_device"

  def connected_devices
    from_links.map(&:to_device) + to_links.map(&:from_device)
  end
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :from_device, class_name: "Device"
  belongs_to :to_device, class_name: "Device"
end
```

LinksController =

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @link = Link.new(link_params)
    @device = Device.find_by(en: params[:link][:from_device])
    if @link.save
      flash[:success] = "Link created."
      redirect_to device_path(@device)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

 private

   def link_params
     params.require(:link).permit(:from_device, :to_device, device_attributes: [:en])
   end
end
```

DevicesController =

```
class DevicesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])
    @linked_devices = @device.connected_devices
  end

private

  def device_params
    params.require(:device).permit(:name, :en, :system_ip, :router_ip, :pop, :chassis_mode, :code_version)
  end
```

CreateLinks Database =

```
class CreateLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :links do |t|
      t.references :from_device
      t.references :to_device
    end
  end
```

Create New Link Form =

```
<% provide(:title, 'New Link') %>
<h1> Create New Link </h1>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= form_for(@link, url: links_path(params[:id])) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @link %>

    <%= f.label :from %>
    <%= f.select :from_device, options_for_select(@devices), :include_blank => true, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :to %>
    <%= f.select :to_device, options_for_select(@devices), :include_blank => true, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: What is giving that error? I think it is telling you that whatever varibable is throwing the error is a string, and it's expecting a Device id.

Comment: It says that this line is where the error is.... Extracted source (around line #8): def create @link = Link.new(link_params). It happens where clicking click the submit button to save 'Create New Link'.

Comment: Can you post your params in the question too?

Comment: Sure :) I have included link_params and device_params in the controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Links model, you have an association to the columns `from_device` and `to_device`. You want to associate the Links table through whatever the foreign key is. So something like:

```
has_many :links, foreign_key: "from_device"
has_many :links, foreign_key: "to_device"
```

see if that helps. Same for your Device model.